# Twitter Bootstrap accordion jump to section and open

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an accordion with 17 sections that contains crosslinks to other sections. Pre-Bootstrap, this worked with  some paragraph IDs and java to open the item.
On clicking a link in one section, the user jumped to another section which expanded.
Is it possible to replicate this using Twitter's Bootstrap (3.0)?

I've seen a few questions similar to this but with no responses!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need link to do that.

1) define classes for your `<a>` tag.
e.g: `<a class="goToTab1">go to tab 1</a>`

2) trigger the event when users click your `<a class="goToTab1">go to tab 1</a>`

```
$(".goToTab1").onclick(function(){
  $("#tab1").trigger("click");
}
```